# customized Ubuntu 14.04 - DNS doesn't work

Tags: networking, live-usb, dns

I've made a Ubuntu 14.04 VM, customized it a bit (apps, etc), and created an .iso via REMASTERSYS. I then made a bootable USB w/ unetbootin.

The DNS works on the VM and on multiple laptops in the house but the bootable USB fails to resolve URLs. The bootable USB does successfully connect to the internet and can ping IPs.

I've searched and tried editing the /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head  and base files, I've tried adding google DNS (8.8.8.8) in the network manager, nothing works. (It's worth noting I make these changes on the VM, reboot, then create the .iso again and make it bootable).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in 12.04 once. I tried the following to solve the issue.

I've renamed the **resolv.conf** file:

```
$ cd /etc
$ sudo mv resolv.conf resolv.conf.backup
```

I've also commented out the *dnsmasq* from the **NetworkManager.conf** file with

```
$ sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

by putting a "#". It ended up:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
#dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Then I restarted the *network-manager* service

```
$ sudo restart network-manager
```

If that does not work, I would like a output from the `nm-tool`(NetworkManager Tool) you need to run.

Comment: Unfortunately sir it seems those steps disabled DNS in the VM (didn't try scraping an iso via REMASTERSYS). State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] 
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:0C:29:4F:4E:7A

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.9
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1